# Perl/DBI/FreeTDS/SQLAzure Some inserts ignored

Tags: perl, azure-sql-database, dbi, freetds

I've got an intermittent problem with Perl using DBI and FreeTDS (on Ubuntu) to insert some data into SQL Azure.  The problem may occur and some rows ignored and then I can just run it again without a problem.

Script:

```
print "Importing File $file: to Staging Table\n";
    open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

$dbh->do("EXEC DWTOOLS.InitStage;") or die $DBI::errstr ; #truncates the table

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO DWSTAGE.CDRImport (LINE) VALUES(?);") or die $DBI::errstr ;
    my $counter = 0;
    while( my $line = <$info>)  {
            $line =~ s/\r?\n$//;
            $counter++;
    print "Loading line $counter: $line\n" ;
            my $rc = $sth->execute($line) or die $DBI::errstr ;
            print "Result: $rc\n";
    }
    close $info;


print "\nChecking Data Warehouse: $counter lines expected\n" ;
my $checksth = $dbh->prepare("EXEC DWTOOLS.CheckStage ?;") or die $DBI::errstr ;
    my $checkrc = $checksth->execute($counter) or die $DBI::errstr ;

my @row;
while ( @row = $checksth->fetchrow_array(  ) ) {
    print "Row: @row\n";
}
```

gives the output:

```
Importing File filename: to Staging Table
Loading line 1: data redacted
Result: 1
Loading line 2: data redacted
Result: 1
etc. etc. with no indication of errors
Loading line 165: data redacted
Result: 1
Loading line 166: data redacted
Result: 1

Checking Data Warehouse: 166 lines expected
Row: 35 166
Row: 35 166
Loading to Data Warehouse
```

So when I look at the table, it shows that all the beginning rows are missing up to a certain point when it started working - reliably - until the end - so basically, the last 35 lines of the file are loaded and they start at 1 going up to 35 where line 1 is actually line (166-35+1) or whatever.  The table in Azure has a PK, clustered IDENTITY column, and this starts off at 1 and there are no gaps, so it's like the first so many inserts have been dropped without any indication of error.  This happens on a variety of files, a variety of sizes and at a variety of places in the file.

The files are processed in a loop, with each file being opened, processed and closed, in case that has any bearing on this odd behavior.  The statement IS re-prepared once for each file, but the SQL Azure connection is maintained for the life of the program if that could be causing an issue.  I'd still expect the program to die if there was a connection failure, but judging by the lack of error codes coming back from the execute, I'm not confident I would get any indication of an error.

If I just go ahead and rerun the program, all the lines come in and everything is fine.

I'm not sure what conclusion to draw.  Right now, my conclusion is that FreeTDS is buggy and unreliable.

Comment: Do you need to $dbh->commit()  somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the DB is executing the insert before the truncate process has finished. If this is a stored procedure you could add some kind of flag that it is complete and check this before moving on. Or better still wrap the entire set of db calls into a transaction.

Comment: Well, it's been a long time and I abandoned attempting to go to this database from Linux.  I guess that's possible if the connection was somehow allowing multiple simultaneous operations and returning before the first stored procedure was complete.  It didn't have that problem on Windows.